# How do I go to hell?

Tags: achievements, glitch-2011

I go once, squish grapes, eat to brush off pooped, then do stuff to get my energy to 0, but can't get back to hell. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to work on the achievements for visiting hell.

Comment: Well, if you can't get into hell, obviously you aren't doing *anything* wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can only go to hell once per game-day.
You get the debuff Pooped when your energy is very low(5% of max energy) with a duration matching the time until the next game day, which is every four earth hours.

Comment: Usually 9am to 5pm.

Answer (score 2):

Get your energy down to low levels. Then, do one of the following:

- Drink a [beer](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Beer) for a energy debuff that takes 35 energy over time.
- Do some [No-No Powder](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/No-No_Powder), then wait until the rush and the crash wear off.
- [Idle at 0 energy](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Hell). Eventually, you'll croak.

I did notice that, the one time I died, I got to 0 energy almost immediately after I came back and didn't die right away. Since you start with low energy after a death, my assumption was that there was a small forgiveness timer that gave you a chance to recover so that you didn't immediately end up back in Hell via performing one or two actions to get something that allowed you to recharge.

Comment: I think I'm really asking for the duration of the forgiveness timer. If we can find that, we've got an answer.

Comment: @antony.trupe: I don't know for sure, but my guess is that it's tied to one of the debuffs you get when you die ([Pooped](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Pooped) or [Super Pooped](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Super_Pooped)) and that you'd be able to die once you got rid of the debuff (by getting more energy or waiting for the next game day, respectively).

Comment: I tried that, and am still unable to get back to hell. It seems you can only go once per day.